# Asp.net skin file Dynamically change classes

Tags: asp.net, css, class

I need to change all classes dynamically in asp.net (visual basic) based on some condition. Using a skin file seems logical, but I am not sure how to assign it. Just to clarify, I need something like below(pseudo code):

```
if(button.clicked)
change class="makeRed makeBold"
to
class="makeBlue makeBold"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is you want to change theme at runtime which is a little bit tricky.

One solution can be:

1. Create one session variable which will hold current theme value
2. On button click event assign value to session variable.
3. During Page_preInit Event assign this variable value to Page.Theme property.
4. Stop page loading and reload same page again using server.transfer method

   ```
   protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string thm;
       thm = (string)Session["MyTheme"];
       if (thm != null)
       {
          Page.Theme = thm;
       }
       else
       {
          Session["MyTheme"] = "makeRed";
          Page.Theme = "makeRed";
       }
   }

   protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["MyTheme"] = "makeBlue";
       Server.Transfer(Request.FilePath);
   }
   ```

Please check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18300/How-to-change-page-theme-in-asp-net-2-0-dynamicall) link (although it is written in c#).

Comment: please provide more of an answer than just a link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Ended up using a variant of what you wrote :)

Answer (score 2):

All ASP.NET controls have a `.CssClass` property.  You should be able to set the `CssClass` property to "makeRed makeBold".

Comment: I know I can do that, but the issue is, I need to change all the button/text/textbox classes. It would be much easier to change just one property.

Comment: This may be easier to do in jQuery, then.  You can find all items with a given class, then change it.  http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: yes, however, I would prefer a solution from within asp.net or css as you need javascript enabled for jquery to work.

Comment: That's a valid concern, but I'd rather spend time coding up a "Please enable JavaScript" message than figuring out how to do something that is so trivial in jQuery.

Comment: Yep, I would too, but one of the requirements if to make the website look good without javascript. :/ Thanks anyway for the answer, it may help others.